# Automate script to trigger build in TFS

Tags: c#, tfs, automation, source-control-explorer

I got a requirement to automate below tasks in TFS branch but I don't have any experience with TFS. Could anyone help me in providing the tips to accomplish to start this task in C#.

1. Run/execute 2 power shell scripts
2. Delete folders in source Control Explorer and then insert new folders
3. Build the solution and initiate the build in case of no issues.

I do above things manually and now asked to automate the script to reduce the work load.

Comment: Which version of TFS do you use?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to get started from Azure Pipelines documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/?view=azure-devops-2019

You accomplish your requirement by defining a pipeline. You define pipelines using the YAML syntax or through the user interface (Classic).

In Pipeline, you could add a [PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops-2019) to run a PowerShell script, invoke [tf commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands?view=azure-devops) to delete or add files to TFVC, and add [Visual Studio Build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops-2019) to build your project. The pipeline using user interface (Classic) looks likethe screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the flow. I will take a look at the above documentations.

Comment: I will take a loot at it this weekend but after reading your answer, I feel like I will get my task done. I will surely accept it as an answer once I start going through the documentation. Thanks.